# Need to implement Native splash screen for 2 seconds in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have used flutter plugin `flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.2`

I need to implement splash screen exact for 2 seconds with custom image. I tried all examples from plugin description but not worked perfectly.

```
flutter_native_splash:

  background_image: "assets/images/splash.png"
```

Comment: Check out [this link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash#3-set-up-app-initialization-optional)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to display a Flutter native splash screen for an exact amount of time, because the splash is displayed while the Flutter framework is loaded.  Depending on the processing speed of the device, this may take more or less time.  Conceivably, on an older device, it could last longer than two seconds even if you did not add an additional delay.

Comment: Well there is actually a functionality to remove the splash screen on a precise moment (for example using a Future.Delayed), but it obviously works only after the app has been loaded. [Source](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash#3-set-up-app-initialization-optional)

Comment: @Dani3le_ your suggestion will not produce an *exact* delay because it cannot account for the time needed to load the app.

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant by "*but it obviously works only after the app has been loaded*".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in main method:

```
void main() async{
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2))
      .then((value) => FlutterNativeSplash.remove());
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using flutter splash screen instead try this
add the image in scaffold

```
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: FadeInImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/splash.png"),//some animation
            height: 400,
            fadeInDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),//transparent_image: ^2.0.0 add this to pub.yaml file
          ),
        )
    );
```

//call this function from init

```
    void userData() async{
        setState(() {
          Timer(
              Duration(seconds: 2),
                  ()=> );
        });
}
```

Screen to which you want to navigate after flash screen

Answer (score 0):

After loading everything in your main dart you can set a timer for splash screen

```
void main() async {
  final widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
  if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
    await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
      SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky,
      overlays: [
        SystemUiOverlay.bottom,
        SystemUiOverlay.top,
      ],
    );
  }
  AppTheme.setTransparentStatusBar(
    darkIcons: false,
  );
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox(Constants.prefs);
  await bootstrap(
    () => const App(),
  );

  /// Here after loading everything we are giving a 4 seconds delay.
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4), FlutterNativeSplash.remove);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve the Splash Screen so that it is displayed until you remove it.

Before you start your app, Preserve the splash screen

```
void main() {
  // This code enables the Splash Screen to be active unless manually removed
  var widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

In the Material App definition setup a timer in the build method to wait for 2 seconds before removing the Splash Screen

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // This will keep you SplashScreen up for exactly 2 seconds
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {FlutterNativeSplash.remove(); });
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Coffee Rewards',
      
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```